# Do Ruby hashes have a method like `reject!` that returns matching items?

Tags: ruby, hash

Do Ruby hashes have a method like `reject!` that returns matching items and leaves only non-matching ones in the hash? For instance:

```
planets = {'Mars' => 2, 'Jupiter' => 63, 'Saturn' => 47}

few_moons = planets.some_method! do |planet, moon_count|
  moon_count < 50
end

few_moons #=> {'Mars'  => 2, 'Saturn' => 47}
planets   #=> {'Jupiter' => 63}
```

`reject!` returns the original hash, minus the rejected items. `partition` is close, but it returns arrays of tuples, not hashes, and doesn't modify the original hash.

I don't see anything like this in the docs, and wanted to ask around before rolling my own.

Comment: I think `partition` is closest, and not much work to wrap to suit your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
few_moons, many_moons = 
  planets.partition { |planet, moon_count| moon_count < 50 } \
  .map{ |v| Hash[v] }
```

Comment: Nice: `Hash['Jupiter', 63] #=> {"Jupiter"=>63}`

Comment: In this case `Hash[[['Jupiter', 63], ...]] #=> {"Jupiter"=>63, ...}`

Answer (score 4):

One workaround is to use a Proc twice:

```
moon_filter = Proc.new {|planet, moon_count| moon_count < 50 }
few_moons   = planets.select(&moon_filter)
lotsa_moons = planets.reject(&moon_filter)
planets     = lotsa_moons
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
planets_with = planets.group_by do |planet, moon_count|
  moon_count < 50 ? :many_moons : :few_moons
end

few  = planets_with[:few_moons]
many = planets_with[:many_moons]
```

However, that will map to an array of arrays instead of an array of hashes. To fix that:

```
planets_with.merge!(planets_with) { |key, values| Hash[values] }
```

Comment: Where do I get the non-matching planets back? `select!` discards them.

Comment: @NathanLong, apologies; I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

### Rolled my own

```
class Hash
  def reject_and_return!(&block)
    matches = {}
    self.each do |k, v|
      matches[k] = self.delete(k) if block.call(k, v)
    end
    matches
  end
end
```

Works as expected:

```
planets = {'Mars' => 2, 'Jupiter' => 63, 'Saturn' => 47}

few_moons = planets.reject_and_return! do |planet, moon_count|
  moon_count < 50
end

few_moons #=> {'Mars'  => 2, 'Saturn' => 47}
planets   #=> {'Jupiter' => 63}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Hash[] constructor will take the arrays back from partition and turn them into hashes the way you want.  It's not a single line, but I think it's cleaner:

a, not_a = {a: 'b', c: 'd', e: 'f'}.partition{|k,v| k == :a}
a=Hash[a]
not_a = Hash[not_a}